# Understanding the concept behind Microsoft Computer Vision- Analyze an Image. Also extract metadata of image from different search engines

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

My task is to upload an image and get as much information as I can get about the image or in different words its metadata (not exif) like - what is it, caption, price, what does it do, application, etc. I have to compare it among different search engines.

This is somewhat similar to Microsoft's cognitive services- Computer Vision- [Analyze an image](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/)
I have following questions -

1. What is the science behind above? I need some direction and guidelines as to what shouls I know or search to make something in python resemble to Microsoft's Computer Vision. Has there been made a similar program before on Github or somewhere?
2. The above shows limited info and doesn't give related searches. If I get the metadata as I asked above, I need to relate it to similar/connected objects from the image and describe them. Like with semantic mapping.

An example to the above question(s) will be - If I have a keyboard image on a cardboard; and when I input this image our program should say - 1. it is a keyboard, 2. it is found on this and that website (these things gathered from different search engines), 3. its price, use/ application, 4. Mouse and computer and CPU like similar objects to be shown with it.

Thank you very much in advance. I hope I was able to explain it properly.